# Integrating the Google Translator API with CFML

Tags: cfml, google-translator-toolkit

I need to retrieve some data from a database using CFQUERY, and then translate that data into another language (like Spanish, Chinese, etc).- The Google Translator will be sufficient for now since the data consists of simple instructions and not a long article.

The JavaScript function that Google provides causes a dropdown menu to appear when the page is loaded. I want the translation to take place automatically, having selected the language on a previous page.

googtrans can be put in the URL to translate the whole page. However I only want to translate the database content - not the entire page. So, for example, part of the page  would be in English and the other part (from the database) in Spanish / Chinese.

I found a good article on this on a blog some five years old. However it is evident that Google have changed their API since then, and so the blog code no longer works.

Can anyone cast any light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems too obvious an answer that I googled "[google translate API](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google%20translate%20api)" and this was from one of the sublinks off the first result ("[Translate API Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#background-operations)").

Doesn't this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
```

achieve exactly what you want?

or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In fact I need one of the Google Translate gadgets as if I have the full API I have to pay each time a visitor opens the page!

Comment: Sorry, this was submitted before I finished writing.